# Highcharts - export current state of a chart

Tags: highcharts, export

The export method of Highcharts uses the chart's initial state rather than the latest state according to the user's interaction. If you show/hide some series, then export the chart, you still get all series rather than what the chart actually shows.

```
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart',
            defaultSeriesType: 'line',
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Expression Profile',
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Reference: act'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['14das-seedling','25das-aerial','35das-aerial',
                         '42das-rosette','42das-stem','53das-stem',
                         '53das-inflores'],
            title: {
                text: 'Development stages',
                margin:20
            }

        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {                                            
                text: 'Log10 act'
            },

            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },

        legend: {
            margin:20
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>mir'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                this.x +' <br/>log10:'+ this.y ;
            }
        },

        series: [
            {
                name: '156a',
                data: [-2.75607, -3.41066, -4.10053, -4.63856, 
                       -4.73462,-4.6145,-3.90987]
            },
            {
                name: '156b',
                data: [-4.15935, -6.54969, -6.70229, -5.80646, 
                       -5.68092,-5.38481,-5.96406]
            },
            {
                name: '156c',
                data: [-4.83317, -5.52142, -4.94995, -5.47179, 
                       -4.97123,-4.86163,-5.12806]
            },
            {
                name: '156d',
                data: [0, -5.93499, -5.41856, -5.88918, 
                       -6.70304,-5.69335,-5.39792]
            },
            {
                name: '156e',
                data: [-4.0707, -6.1185, -6.58353, -6.17734, 
                       -6.84433,-5.4114,-5.37817]
            },
            {
                name: '156f',
                data: [-3.97561, -5.02619, -5.67834, -5.65722, 
                       -5.76238,-4.51125,-5.30344]
            },
            {
                name: '156g',
                data: [-3.81589, -2.50758, -2.41623, -3.63983, 
                       -3.73004,-2.90055,-3.61997]
            },
            {
                name: '156h',
                data: [-4.31169, -5.74017, -5.55419, -5.26679,
                       -5.01009,-4.99596,-5.68062]
            }
         ] 
    });
});
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sherlock85/safKs/

Is it possible to export the current state of the chart?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For me is exporting the latest state even when I modify the chart. I guess if you do a chart.redraw() after your modifications it will export the latest state. Also try to upgrade to the latest version of highcharts.

Comment: I use the latest highcharts version, but still the exporting works only in initial state. The situation is the same at official highcharts website in demo gallery: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/. Where should I add chart.redraw() function?

Comment: I don't see any user interaction on your example, can you be more specific? if you add some events related with a point for example, in the callback of the event you can add the chart.redraw()

Comment: Thank you for helping me, Elzo. In my example: http://jsfiddle.net/sherlock85/safKs/ you can see 8 series, all of them are visible. Let's say I'd like to hide some series, so I click a couple of these guys from the legend. And this state of chart (with some hidden series) I would like to export as a picture. But sadly, as a result I receive a picture of my chart in its initial state (with all series visible).

Comment: this is not a change in the actual chart object so redraw will not work. look at this example to actual remove a serie http://jsfiddle.net/ebuTs/14/, after this you will remove the serie for real and it will not appear anymore in the export

Comment: I see. But this option removes series permanently, from both, legend and chart. I rather thought about showing and hiding series.

Comment: There is a feature request on highcharts. http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general. you can ask for an "export only visible" functionality there.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in version 2.1.5 of Highcharts. I believe the comment from the [changelog](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog) seen below addresses your issue.

> Exported charts now respect user set min and max after zoom and visibility option.

Answer (score 0):

The problem still persists if you have used the following code in your chart:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            ...,
            events: {
                load: function(event) {
                    this.series.forEach(function(d,i){if(d.options.id==1)d.hide()})
                }
            }    
        },...
```

This piece of code is responsible for initially hiding series in your graph (with id==1 in this example). It seems it has the negative side effect of not being able to export the current state of your graph.

Remove it, and the initial problem is solved.

If you still want to keep the 'initial hiding' of data series, and you use AJAX (and jQuery) for example to fetch the data, use the following kind of code instead:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: myURL,
    data: {data: myData},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        chart.series[0].setData(data[0], true);
        chart.series[1].setData(data[1], true);
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        chart.series[1].hide();
    }
});
```